# React custom mount hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I always forget to add empty dependencies array in my `useEffect` hook in React to run the effect only once. That's why I decided to use a custom hook with a clear intention in it's name to run only once on mount. But I don't understand why is it running twice?

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function useOnMount(f) {
  const isMountedRef = React.useRef(false);
  console.log("ref1", isMountedRef.current);
  if (!isMountedRef.current) {
    f();
    isMountedRef.current = true;
    console.log("ref2", isMountedRef.current);
  }
}

export default function App() {
  useOnMount(() => {
    console.log("useOnMount");
  });

  return <div>Hello useOnMount</div>;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
ref1 false
useOnMount 
ref2 true
ref1 false
useOnMount 
ref2 true
```

I use `ref` hook to keep mutable flag between renders. But I can't understand why `isMountedRef.current` is `true` on the first render and reverts to `false` on the second render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep forgetting the dependencies array? Why not just remember to write it once in your custom hook?

```
function useOnce (once) {
  return useEffect(once, [])
}
```

Using it in your `App` -

```js
function App () {
  useOnce(_ => console.log("useOnce"))

  return <div>hello</div>
}
```

Here's a demo -

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React

function useOnce (once) {
  return useEffect(once, [])
}

function App () {

  useOnce(_ => alert("Wake up. It's time to make candy!"))

  const [candy, setCandy] =
    useState(0)

  const earn =
    <button onClick={_ => setCandy(candy + 1)}>
      Make candy
    </button>

  const spend =
    <button onClick={_ => setCandy(candy - 10)}>
      Buy Chocolate (10)
    </button>

  return <div>
    <b>Candy Box</b>
    <p>Alert will only appear one time after component mounts</p>
    <p>
      {earn}
      {(candy >= 10) && spend}
    </p>
    <p>You have {candy} candies</p>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That's definitly a better way to implement on-mount hook. Simple and straightforward.

Comment: It doesn't work now: "warning  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'once'. Either include it or remove the dependency array (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)". When I add 'once' to dependencies it is called on every run. When I add useCallback/useMemo I still need to specify all dependencies so it is the same as to specify them in useEffect and function will trigger not once. Total madness.

Comment: @Dron007 you probably made a mistake somewhere. `once` is not a dependency of itself, that wouldn't make any sense. try pasting your code somewhere and link it if you would like me to review.

Comment: @Mulan Here is what I mean (the warning) and the way how to fix it: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-tesla-qd51hx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me and doesn't generate `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` warnings.

```
function useOnce (once) {
  const [ res ] = useState(once)
  return res
}
```

Usage:

```
function App () {
  useOnce(() => {
    console.log("useOnce")
    // use any App props or result of other hooks
    ...
  })

  return <div>hello</div>
}
```

It was recommended [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-create-expensive-objects-lazily) for another task but it works well as a `componentDidMount` replacement. Any parameters may be used inside the function. Just make sure you really don't need to monitor changes of props.